# AJAX call not triggered on show.bs.modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button which is supposed to trigger a modal with a contact form. Part of the `show.bs.modal` function is an AJAX call to my DB to get some file details which are then meant to be shown in the modal-body.

The problem is that the modal does indeed open, but with no `modal-body` content, which means that the JavaScript code to trigger to the AJAX call is not working. I do not see any network activity in the browser debug menu, no call to the PHP file, and even an `alert` on top of the JS code telling me that that a button was pressed is not triggered. It seems like the whole JS code is circumvented, yet the modal still shows.

The same code works in another project, anyone has any idea as to why this is happening?

Button:

```
<div class="card-footer bg-light text-center">
    <button id="modal_btn" name="modal_btn" type="button" class="btn bg-teal-400" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_contact_form" data-imgid="'.$row['image_id'].'" data-keyboard="true">
        <span class="icon-ico-mail4"></span>  Anfragen
    </button>
</div>
```

Modal:

```
<!-- Contact form modal -->
<div id="modal_contact_form" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-teal-300">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Kaufanfrage - Artikel #1234</h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn bg-teal-300">Nachricht Senden</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /contact form modal -->
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    // DISPLAY EDIT RECORD MODAL
    $('#modal_contact_form').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            //var button = $(event.relatedTarget)   // Button that triggered the modal
            window.alert("button clicked.");
            var imgid = $(event.relatedTarget).data('imgid')    // Extract info from data-* attributes
            var modal = $(this);
            var dataString = 'action=contact&imgid=' + imgid;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./assets/ajax/ajax_action.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    modal.find('.modal-body').html(data);
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });  
    });
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal','#modal_contact_form', function (event) {
// TODO ....
});
```

Or you can use the `onclick` button trigger instead of modal show trigger

```
$("#modal_btn").click(function(event){
// TODO ...
});
```

Comment: the `onclick` button trigger did the trick... now I am just curious as to why? :D Thank you

Comment: one drawback of `onclick` is that it breaks this code: `var imgid = $(event.relatedTarget).data('imgid')` Seems like `.relatedtarget` doesnt like a button trigger event.

Comment: in the `onclick` function, you can use `$(this).data('imgid')` here instead of using the event .. scince the clicking event is being triggered with this button

and for the modal .. use this: `var modal = $("#modal_contact_form");`

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
  const bsModal = document.querySelector('#exampleModal');    
    $(bsModal).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
       // YOUR CODE HERE....
    })
```